# Why don't dwarves use bins in stockpiles?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In the *Finished Goods Stockpile #30* below, I've set the `Max Bin` option to 260, but my dwarves are still not using bins to store the stone crafts, though I can see they have 156 free bins available from the Stock screen. Why is it?

[image]

Comment: 260 is a rather large limit. Does your problem still occur if you try to use a maximum of 255 or 127 bins? Also, have you checked that there are free bins your dwarves are actually allowed to use? (Claimed, no burrows, no angry dragons scaring away your dwarves, etc.)

Comment: Does the goods stockpile have any Take settings, and if so does it include the bin stockpile? Does the bin stockpile have any Give settings, and if so does it include the goods stockpile?

Comment: @aphid I would say "yes" to all of your questions. Today those little dwarves have finally started storing items in bins! Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @Paul I would say "yes" to all of your questions. Today those little dwarves have finally started storing items in bins! Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Binning behaviour gets weird with stockpiles that are already full; I'm still not sure what exactly triggers the binning frenzy, but I can confirm they take their sweet time. The most likely trigger I could find is that they wait until a slot is made open in the stockpile, then they add a bin; then the bin gets filled with 'loose' items present in the pile, which opens new slots, which allows for more bins, goto 2.

Answer (score 1):

I'll make the assumption that you're intrested in making the dwarves use the bins and not just curious about the inner machinations of their tipsy minds.

From my experience and a bit of research, dwarves are more prone to binning if the bins are stored in a furniture stockpile rather than clogging up a workshop.